# Create view in mysql with max value for each table in database

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, sql-view, union-all

I have many tables with the same columns in a mysql database.

I would like to create a view to store the maximum value of one of the columns and the table name.

Something like vw_max_table_vals
TableName String(100)
maxVal timestamp

How can I do this in mysql.

Regards

Comment: It might be better to consider why you have several identical tables.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed list of tables, you can use `union all`. Assuming that you have three tables (`t1`, `t2` and `t3`) with a column called `col`:

```
create view myview as
select 't1' as table_name, max(col) as max_col from t1
union all select 't2', max(col) from t2
union all select 't3', max(col) from t3
```

Note that this requires the datatype of `col` to be consistent across the three tables.